# modify sick lidar parameters on husky_gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 14.04 Indigo. I am trying to figure out the best way to add a hokuyo lidar to the husky in gazebo world. So far, from the [husky move base demo](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20Move%20Base%20Demo) ( `roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch`),  It already has a `sick_lms1xx` laser on it.

Since, I need to mount the hokuyo lidar on the husky for my simulation, I was thinking of just modifying `husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro` from this [github source](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_description/urdf), and change the sick_lms1xx laser configuration such as min, max, increment angles to match hokuyo lidar configuration. However, I can't find all these parameters. Dose anyone know how I can modify them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295700/modify-sick-lidar-parameters-on-husky_gazebo/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-29**:
Which package/node do you use for sick LMS1xx simulation?

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-06-29**:
i believe is this package [here](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx/tree/0.1.6). it produce a `/scan` node.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-29**:
I do not see simulation in there. How is node started in launch file?

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-06-29**:
I am still new to gabezo and ros, but I think the simulated sick_lms1xx starts the `/scan` topic in `urdf/husky.urdf.xacro` file, [link](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/f104e4532cf9dd799f27879cb010166f35d03890/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro#L146).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`husky.urdf.xacro` is including `accessories/sick_lms1xx_mount.urdf.xacro` which in turn is including `sick_lms1xx.urdf.xacro` from [the LMS1xx package](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/LMS1xx/blob/master/urdf/sick_lms1xx.urdf.xacro). There are the parameter you are looking for.

This would obviously be the fastet way to change this.

But you could also use a hokuyo urdf (depending on the actual scanner) and replace the sick one with this...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1